# Connection to MySQL Server not working

Tags: mysql

I want to connect to my SQL Server on my remote server. I have installed MySQL on this server with apt-get and set up all necessary details. On the server everything works fine. When I want to connect with the MySQL Workbench, I cannot connect with any user at all.

I logged into MySQL in Ubuntu and created a new user first:

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I opened the my.cnf file:

```
port 3306
bind-address 127.0.0.01 (DO I NEED HERE MY REMOTE SERVER IP?)
service mysql restart
```

My questions would be:

1) why is the host 127.0.0.1 on my remote server?

2) In the workbench connection setup: which hostname is correct? my server IP or 127.0.0.1

3)I get the message: Failed to connect to MySQL. Access denied. So I think the user is the issue?

4) Do I need to change the cnf?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create the user and configure the right permission did you

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

After you change your `my.cnf` did you restart Mysql?

> Stop and Start from XAMPP Panel control

Change

```
bind address=127.0.0.1
```

to

```
bind-address=YOUR-SERVER-IP
```

Comment: You were faster than me. I just wanted to edit my text. Yes. I did the Flush and restarted Mysql.

Comment: i found the issue change `bind address=YOUR-SERVER-IP` to `bind-address=YOUR-SERVER-IP`

Comment: Sorry.. was a typo as well in the question. the config file has bind-address. Do I need to add my remote server IP there? And which hostname should I add in the workbench? as well the remote server IP?

Comment: @ISARFAKTOR try to change the ip with your server IP

Comment: yes, you have to use server IP and connect with MYSQL Workbench with your server IP

Comment: Cool! have fun with it! Just to let you know, if you work on Linux you can connect to Mysql via SSH and you don't need to configure all these nightmare and it is more secure, but that is another story. Cheers!